# Perl _SYNTAX is undefined

Tags: perl

Hi I'm getting this error in Perl:

```
'_SYNTAX' is undefined at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Config/Simple.pm line 457.
Compilation failed in require at producer.pl line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at producer.pl line 14.
```

producer.pl is the name of the file.

At line 14 I have:

```
use DatabaseSql;
```

In DatabaseSql.pm, I have this code that is triggering that error:

```
    use ReadConf;
    use Cwd qw(cwd);

    my $config = ReadConf->new( { file => "$path/../config/sws_snmpcollector.cfg" } );
    $config = $config->read_conf(); # Levanta los parametros de configuracion

    my $prod_batch = $config->{producer_batch};
    print $prod_batch;
```

But if I run : perl DatabaseSql.pm it runs fine and the number 2 appears (which is the value of producer_batch).

Also in my producer.pl I'm running this:

```
    my $config = ReadConf->new( { file => "$path/config/sws_snmpcollector.cfg" } );
    $config = $config->read_conf(); # Levanta los parametros de configuracion

    my $producer_frec = $config->{producer_frec};
```

And it runs fine.

I've searched for that error but I didn't succeed.
Thanks!

EDIT:

ReadConf.pm

```
package ReadConf;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Config::Simple;/pod/Config::Simple)

## Constructor
sub new {

   my $class = shift;
   my $params = shift;


   my $self = {
                                'file' => $params->{file}
   };

   bless $self,$class;

   return $self;

}
```

There're more code but it's too large.

Comment: What is this `ReadConf`? From looking at the code of `Config::Simple` the error happens if the syntax of the config file is not defined. In my opinion the error should be somewhere in `ReadConf` where it uses `Config::Simple`.

Comment: ReadConf is in the same folder that DatabaseSql.


-----Tree:
-producer.pl
-lib
-config



in config there is one file:
-sws_snmpcollector.cfg




In lib there are:
-DatabaseSql.pm
-ReadConf.pm
-And some others modules.

Comment: Like Steffen said, we need to see `ReadConf`

Comment: What is in your `$path` variable? Is it absolute or relative? When you run `perl DatabaseSql.pm` and it works as expected you are in `lib` ?

Comment: I've edited my post with ReadConf.
When I run DatabaseSql.pm I'm in "/lib" and when I run producer.pl I'm in a folder before /lib .

My path is relative, I'm using Cwd to obtain it ( $path=cwd;).

Comment: When you `use DatabaseSql` from `producer.pl` your cwd is probably above `lib` . You don‘t want the `/..` in your path. Also check for existence of the file and add error handling to your code.

Comment: @clamp you rule! That was the error, thank you so much. I'm going to add an error handler.

Comment: @Foxssg I should add that it is error prone to use `cwd()` to obtain the path. Your script might be called from anywhere, so `cwd()` does not always point to your scripts directory. You should use`$RealBin` from the core module `FindBin` instead. Documentation: [FindBin](https://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html#DESCRIPTION)

Comment: @clamp thanks I'll check it out now!